# Can I install an app to the simulator without the source code?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I have a client who wants to just drag and drop the binary to run it in the simulator.

I want to build the simulator app and email it to them.

What can the client do to install this in the simulator?

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as they are on the same version of the target O/S as you you should be fine.  Look here on your local machine:

~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/

That is where the apps are stored.

Watch this directory and grab everything that is added when you install the app.  Then you can zip those materials and have your client un-zip them under the same path.

Comment: I'll give this a shot, just hope the files aren't machine specific

Comment: I was curious about this, so I did some more extensive testing.

I only had one machine to test this on, but I was able to manually remove the app from the listed directory, verify the app was no longer installed in the simulator.  I then moved the files back into the Applications directory and unzipped them into a new directory called "test".  The app came up fine in the simulator.

The only variable left is the different machine, but everythng else seems to indicate this is going to work fine.

Comment: The problem with testing on one machine is that if any problem crops up, it'll likely be in the certificate/code-signing area. Part of that information is kept in your keychain which you didn't modify in your test. A more accurate test would be to create a different user account, login and install the SDK on it, then copy the files over and try it in the simulator.

Comment: @MystikSpiral: does the other machine need to have Xcode installed for this to work?

Comment: They are going to need the iPhone/iPad simulator to make this work.  I have not checked, but I do not believe that is available without Xcode.

Answer (score 21):

You can, by executing the command below in the Terminal app.

`xcrun simctl install {simulator_udid} {path of .app file}`

It will install the `.app` file in the referenced simulator.

Note: Make sure that the .app file is built for the simulator (i.e. `i386` or `x86_64`).

Comment: This is the solution that works for Xcode 7.2. All other tricks that I have used in the past no longer work. This is awesome because it is an Apple tool that installs things in the correct place. Any answers here older than 2015 are probably ineffective now.

Comment: If you see "An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=164):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown" You need to start the simulator manually first by finding it in Hardware->Device->{iOS version}

Answer (score 4):

As the poster before me has stated you will find the apps in this folder:

~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/

I needed to copy the following two files:

- A folder with a cryptic name (seams to be some hash)
- And a file with the same name as the folder and the .sb suffix

Put them in the same place on your second computer and start the simulator there:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications

I have tested this on my work computer and on my home computer which has no certificates installed.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't got around to testing yet but my client will need to do this soon.

Comment: With the SDK 3.2 the folder structure has changed the apps are now in: ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.1.3/

Comment: I can't find the .sb files in the folders for version 4.0.2 and 4.3. Any ideas?

Comment: If I remember it correctly these files have gone now and are not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need and worked on the issue in iOS 5 simulator.

You need to run the application at least once. Then you can find your application under the folder path

~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/'simulator version'/Applications/

The folders will have a hashed name.
Find the folder which contains your application and just copy the AppName.app file from that folder. Now you can send that file to your clients.

The clients will to make a folder under the same folder path as mentioned above with any name and copy the AppName.app file and just open the simulator. voila... they will see the app installed in simulator.