# How do you deploy an iPhone app to the simulator from the command line?

Tags: iphone, command-line, simulator

I'm using xcodebuild from the command line to compile several variations of an iPhone app but I've not been able to figure out how to deploy those builds into the iPhone Simulator from the command line.  Could somebody please enlighten me?  Thank you.

Comment: What's the advantage to doing this over just build and go or run from the xcode top-bar?

Comment: I'm building several dozen apps at a time.

Comment: This would be useful to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the open source "iphonesim" and it'll do it for you: http://github.com/jhaynie/iphonesim/

It's small and written in objective C, and it seems to work fine from the command line.

Comment: does it work even now ?? I tried it but not as expected

Answer (score 4):

This was a looong time ago. But if someone is interested
[Simulator_installation_path]/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication [AppFolder_full_path]/[AppName].app/[AppName]

My simulator path was:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS

Comment: Ok, can you specify the error here? Please add the command as well and I can try to help!

Comment: My error was that I was deploying the Release version of the app instead of the Debug

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that using the -sdk iphonesimulator3.0 flag with xcodebuild should generate the .sb files, but this doesn't seem to work.  Maybe it's not possible ?

Answer (score -2):

This topic will tell you how to do it manually, you should be able to automate the process as well:

[Can I install an app to the simulator without the source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947317/can-i-install-an-app-to-the-simulator-without-the-source-code)

Comment: thanks but that topic just explains how to copy an already-deployed-to-simulator project to another machine.

Comment: Just create the mentioned .sb file programatically and copy your executable built for the simulator along with that file into the applications directory in the simulators folder in your Library.