# Are there any keyboard shortcuts or general tips for the iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Can someone provide me with few *shortcuts* for handling **iPhone simulator** which could save my time? Also are there any *console commands* to handle simulator?

If there are, kindly share them with me. I was searching for possible ways to handle *simulator*. Please suggest me few tips regarding the same which might help me knowing the *simulator* better.

Comment: Have you tried to use it with the cursor? I don't think you can handle it with the terminal. It is just an iPhone simulator and you cannot handle the iPhone with the terminal.

Comment: Ok. And what about shortcut keys?

Comment: Umm...click on the menus and see what command-key combinations are assigned to each menu?

Comment: @dasdom : [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207395/how-do-you-deploy-an-iphone-app-to-the-simulator-from-the-command-line) is an example of what I asked for. Though this one won't save any time but I am sure there are more of these.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "handling iPhone simulator"? Do you want to launch it, control it, automate it, or what? Also, why the *random* italics?

Comment: You have edit option with you. If you don't like the text style you may edit it. If stack overflow finds it better it will be edited. By handling iphone simulator, I meant deployment of app on simulator via console commands and commands which can handle operations pertaining to simulator. I have got list of shortcuts, but not enough information on console commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holding the option key with your mouse over the simulator simulates 2-finger gestures.  It's useful for zooming in and out

Control + Option + C to copy the screen

Answer (score 0):

**1. Command-Left Arrow**

Rotate left

**2. Command-Right Arrow**

Rotate right

**3. Command-Shift-H**

Go To Home. Leave the application and return to the springboard home screen.