# Run iPhone/iPad Simulator for Continuous Integration

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, continuous-integration, ios-simulator

I am attempting to run the iOS simulator from the command line. I have found the location where the iPhone Simulator can be run from. My question is whether or not it can receive parameters to specify which device should be launched and what app it should run.

`$ ./Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator`

Does anyone know if there are tricks to this. Knowing more about this would really help with our Continuous Integration process.

---

We now use [WaxSim](https://github.com/square/WaxSim) to automate our iOS applications during CI Builds

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you deploy an iPhone app to the simulator from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207395/how-do-you-deploy-an-iphone-app-to-the-simulator-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Do you only want to open simulator?? or want that a specific app file to be installed and run that on simulator???

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `-SimulateApplication` argument to run your executable in the simulator (executable inside the `.app` bundle)

(you could also compile the project from the command-line like this:)
`xcodebuild -project Test.xcodeproj -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator`

Then for example:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication Test.app/Test`

or

`./Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication Test.app/Test`

Comment: Although, I am getting an error that makes it seem like I need to set the sdk or something...

Comment: elimirls: You may have tried to get the simulator to run MyApp.app, rather than MyApp.app/MyApp.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Xcode 5 on Mavericks.

Answer (score 5):

To launch a specific device you can do:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateDevice "iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)"

Answer (score 4):

Try this in your shell for Xcode 6

```
osascript -e 'activate application "iOS Simulator"'
```

For Xcode 7

```
osascript -e 'activate application "Simulator"'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open Simulator with specific app installed then you can use some of the ready utility to launch simulator. This way it is easy to install the app and run on the simulator. This are the command line utilities that can be run from *Terminal* Window.

1. [iPhoneSim](https://github.com/jhaynie/iphonesim)
2. [ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim)
3. Other are same as above two.

And main thing is all uses same approach to open simulator. (see the project for more details)

Other way (not recommended by me) use script file to run from command.

Comment: Your second link (ios-sim) is now dead.  Also not mentioned is what happens with NSLog/console output.  For example invoking the simulator directly does not show it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xcrun simctl` to list available simulators, launch applications, etc. This tool is present in both Xcode 7 and Xcode 8. If you don't give it a command it will print command line help.

`xcrun simctl launch <UUID> <bundle id of app>` will start the application.