# Possibility of launching an iOS simulator session through a shell command with an argument for screen orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad, ios-simulator

Seeing the horizon of iOS app automated deployment right upon us, I figured I could start by making my tests fully automated.

Going through all the details of the process I've reached a dead end. My application can sometimes display a few UI bugs if it's launched in landscape orientation. Naturally I want to make some unit tests making sure that if this happens my application doesn't get deployed. So the problem I'm facing right now is how can I run the iOS simulator in a defined orientation through the command line.

I know about [iphonesim](https://github.com/jhaynie/iphonesim), but as far as I see it doesn't have such functionality as of yet. Maybe it could be modified... Any Ideas?

Thanks.

---

EDIT: For clarification the issue only happens on the iPad simulator config, since you can launch an app straight into lanscape mode only on the iPad.

Comment: [There are a few undocumented parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10216117/981049) that can be passed to iPhone Simulator when launching it from the command line, but after a 15 minute search, I can't find anything listed or published for orientation.  That's not to say it doesn't exist; it probably does.  You should file a bug with Apple and ask them to *publish* command line options for iPhone Simulator.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Will try to get some info from them.

Comment: Any updates on this one?

Comment: Nope, I didn't get any real response from Apple.