# Run Xcode iOS application from command-line

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa, terminal

OK, so this is all I need:

- I've got an Xcode 4.3 project, all set up
- I want to run in the simulator, given its path, via the terminal

Is this doable? And how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install iPhone application in iPhone Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator)

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8352745/792677 has links to the open source command-line projects launching .app projects in simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best thing to do, if it doesn't have much of a UI, is to create a Mac-targeted version.  Create a side-directory within your project, and create a new Mac project in that, complete with separate `main`, et al.  Then "add existing files" to that project to add the files you want from the original project.

There's also a way to do this within a single Xcode 4 (not Xcode 3) project, vs creating a separate one, but that's a little flaky and this approach is simpler.

If you want to preserve the UI, though, probably the best approach is to just run the app in the emulator.