# Starting iPhone Simulator through command line

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I am able to start the iPhone simulator from command line through the following command:

`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone Simulator -SimulateApplication /TestBuild/testApp.app`

The simulator starts but quits with the message saying "the simulated application quits"

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?
Kindly help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351278/run-iphone-ipad-simulator-for-continuous-integration   see

Comment: ./iphonesim launch ~/tmp/yourproject/build/Debug.simulator/yourproject.app

Comment: May this help you http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2011/12/running-your-ios-app-in-the-simulator-from-the-command-line.html