# Launch iPhone simulator without Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

Is it possible to launch iPhone simulator from line command without using Xcode ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run iPhone/iPad Simulator for Continuous Integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351278/run-iphone-ipad-simulator-for-continuous-integration)

Comment: I just put the simulator on my dock so it's just one click away.. open simulator the normal way then right click > options > add to dock

Comment: @Huangism the question is about launching the simulator from the command line!

Comment: @rckoenes hence I did not put my comment in an answer, I am only stating an alternative

Comment: http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2013/04/launch-iphone-simulator-without-xcode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open `xcode-select --print-path`/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app
```

Comment: You cannot launch an iPhone application from the terminal.

Comment: @Jim  thx so much the simulator is launched but how can i launch a specific application on the simulator

Answer (score -1):

Command + Shift + H is the shortcut which does the work of the home button on the simulator. Use it and it takes it to the menu. If your app is already built, and hasnt been deleted, you find it there.