# How to distribute an iPhone app for testing in the iPhone simulator on testing computers?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Can you distribute an iPhone app for testing in the iPhone simulator on computers that do not have the XCode development tools installed? Can you just install the simulator on a computer for testing?

I have a group of testers that are not developers and do not need to have the dev tools other than the ability to run the simulator to test the app.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to run Iphone app on simulator without using xcode.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919970/need-to-run-iphone-app-on-simulator-without-using-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

The official way to achieve your goal of user acceptance testing without requiring the users to have the development tools is to use Ad-Hoc deployment instead of the simulator.

To conduct an ad-hoc deployment you will need all your testers to have a device (iPhone, iPod touch, or iPad) and you will need to acquire their device's unique identifier UDID. Once you have that you will need to go into the iPhone developer website and create a new deployment signing certificate of type 'ad-hoc', making sure to specify that each of your testers has rights to that build.

By doing this your testers will be able to run the app on real hardware, and will only be required to have iTunes installed on either a Windows or Macintosh computer.

Comment: It's not feasible for the testers to have a device. Thus my inquiry about the simulator.