# How can I run the iPhone/iPad simulator with only the binary

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

I would like to send my iPad app to testers who have xcode on their macs but do not own an iPad.  I don't want to send them my source code.  Is there a way I can send them the app to run in the simulator without sending source code?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to run Iphone app on simulator without using xcode.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919970/need-to-run-iphone-app-on-simulator-without-using-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot send them a Simulated binary. Xcode installs the application just as AppStore would, by assigning a GUID. You could possibly send the whole folder that contains your app (including the Documents folder, Library, etc.) That may possibly work. If your friends have iPads, you can always build for `Ad-Hoc` and let them test that way.

Comment: With respect to sending the whole folder, I can't even start the simulator on my own machine by opening the .app in the iPhone Simulator directory. It doesn't do anything. Wonder if I am missing something.

Comment: How are you trying to open the .app? You simply launch the Simulator, and it should pick up the apps in the directory. If you are double-clicking the ".app" file, that just wont work. Also, clicking on the .app will not open the Simulator. The apps should be located in '/Users/Aaron/Library/Application Support/4.2' (or whatever iOS you are building for. If you are trying to let people test your app, I would suggest the Ad-Hoc route, instead of letting them test in the actual simulator.

Comment: Yes, I was double clicking.  Got that to run.  Thanks.  Wrt Ad Hoc distribution yes I do that with my testers who have devices.  I have some testers with domain expertise who unfortunately don't have iPads.