# Can I test Flash CS5 iOS published SWF's or ipa's without having to load them onto the iPhone every single time?

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

As per the title, is there a simulator or a way for Adobe Device Central to read CS5 created iOS published SWF's or ipa's for testing purposes?

At the moment, I make a change in Flash CS5, publish the SWF and IPA, delete the old version from my phone, drop the new IPA in, re sync and test. This is not good for the workflow.

What are the options for testing and developing?

EDIT:
I am on a Windows machine (Windows 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i do mostly is this.
Change the flash player from iOS to flash lite and run the program in Device Central.
Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're up for using the Simulator instead, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947317/can-i-install-an-app-to-the-simulator-without-the-source-code) could help you load them into the Simulator. Not sure if there are any compatibility issues, but the Simulator does tend to load *significantly* faster than loading to the phone, IME.

Comment: As a heads up, I'm not familiar w/ the CS5 ipa's. I'm speaking from just general iOS Obj-C development.

Comment: Sorry I should have said in the original question that I am using a Windows machine. I will edit the question now.